# Geo Fix command does not pass altitude

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

On Android 2.2 Emulator, the "geo fix" command seems not to be working properly.  The emulator responds "OK", and `onLocationChanged()` is properly called in my program.  However, the `Location` object seems not to be complete - it registers latitude and longitude just fine, but it does not contain an altitude reading: `hasAltitude()` returns `false`.

Any ideas why?

Example emulator commands:

```
geo fix -74 40.75 500
geo fix -77 39 400.0
```

Code snippet:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    System.out.println("onLocationChanged Called");
    if (loc.hasAltitude()) {
        double newalt = loc.getAltitude();
        System.out.println("new altitude: " + newalt);
        gps[ALTITUDE] = newalt;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No altitude fix");
    }
    gps[LONG] = loc.getLongitude();
    System.out.println(gps[LONG]);
    gps[LAT] = loc.getLatitude();
    System.out.println(gps[LAT]);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
onLocationChanged Called
No altitude fix
-74.012333333333333333
40.756666666666666667
onLocationChanged Called
No altitude fix
-77.012833333333333335
39.006499999999999996
```

Comment: Similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054379/why-does-location-getaltitude-always-return-zero-at-least-in-the-emulator

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the emulator and has been reported at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24809