# Can the android emulator simulate altitude with a gpx file?

Tags: android, android-gps

I am trying to simulate motion of the emulator device in the **ddms** perspective. I am using a gpx file which contains  elevation elements, but when my code runs, it only retrieves lat/lon and says that elevation = 0.

My question is, **Can the android emulator be used to simulate altitude, speed etc, or is it just for latitude and longitude data?**

Comment: You can send the emulator a fix via the emulator that includes altitude as an optional value using geo fix <longitude> <latitude> [<altitude>], so yes, it can handle altitude. With a gpx file, dont know, havent done it.

Comment: ok, so it is possible for it to use altitude data in the emulator, but it just doesn't seem to read it from a gpx file... has anyone had any success simulating elevation of tracks data with gpx files?  or kml?

Comment: If you don't find anything better you could read the file yourself and submit a series of fixes including altitude.  To answer your question, you might locate the code of what is currently reading the gpx file and see if it has any altitude capability.

Comment: I've had similar problems; both GPX files with altitude data and inputting altitude with geo fix don't seem to work in the 2.2 emulator. 
And it looks like other people here have had a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292788/geo-fix-command-does-not-pass-altitude

Comment: @blindstuff I don't think it works , I sent elevation values with gpx file but it won't show . I think emulator only shows lat , long values only

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, however it may give you some useful ideas.

What type of provider do you use? There are 2 options: `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` and `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`. My guess is that altitude can only be available if `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` is used.

Also on you `Location` updates (in `LocationListener.onLocationChanged(Location location)`) you can call `location.hasAltitude()`. It returns true if this fix contains altitude information, false otherwise.

**UPDATE**:

So it looks like you are experiencing some emulator issue. I rerember I was on Eclipse 3.4.1 + ADT 0.9.5 + Android 2.0.1 app + WinXP and the only way to feed the emulator with GPS fixes was to use Telnet. So I just created a helper Ruby script for that:

```
require 'net/telnet'

scenario = [
  'sleep 1', 
  'geo fix -121.45356 46.51119 0', 
  'sleep 3', 
  'geo fix -80.45356 45.51119 0'
]

simulator_connection = nil

begin
  simulator_connection = 
    Net::Telnet::new(
      'Timeout' => 5, 
      'Port'    => 5554, 
      'Prompt'  => /(OK|\AKO.*\z)/
    )
rescue Errno::EBADF
  puts '> Error: running Android Emulator not found. Exiting ...'
  exit
end

puts '> got connection to Android Emulator'

begin
  scenario.each do |action|
    if action =~ /\Asleep\s\d+\z/
      puts "> #{action} secs ..."
      eval(action)
    else
      puts "> execute \"#{action}\""
      simulator_connection.cmd(action)
    end
  end
  puts '> job is done, exiting ...'
ensure
  simulator_connection.close
end
```

You see I pass 0 as the altitude (the last param at 'geo fix ...'), however you may try with your non-zero values. If you are not familiar with Ruby, then you could probably adopt the script to your favorite scripting language. Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: I am using the GPS_PROVIDER.  Interestingly, I loaded it onto my phone and took it outside and it worked fine... it could record both speed and altitude.  So it seems like it is indeed related to the gpx file.  The file does contain altitude data.... however it can't seem to get at it... I will see if hasAltitude is triggered...

Comment: @Dave: Please, see the UPDATE section in my post.